# ¿por que los articulos en 0's o null no se muestran en mi reporte final de mysql?

Tags: mysql

recurro a ustedes ya que no he podido resolver este detalle en la sentencia sql, bien, el error que tengo es al momento de realizar la consulta de mis productos clasificados por categoria, ya que cuando filtro con un simple where me da 126 productos, pero cuando incluyo los joins con las demás tablas de entradas, salidas e inventario inicial solo me muestra 49, ya he intentado hacer un if/case para poder poner 0's si es el caso de que no exista registro de ese producto en entradas y salidas.

En conclusión al realizar la consulta solo me arroja los que si tienen entradas y salidas.

Quisiera saber como realizar los cambios a la sentencia de modo que me pueda mostrar todos los productos aún solo teniendo inventario inicial.

Gracias.

Mi sentencia sql:

```
SELECT art.id as Id,
art.name as Producto,
linea.name as 'Categoria',
art.measure as 'U. Medida',
war.quantity as 'Total Inicial',
(sum(pur.quantity)) as 'Total Entradas',
sal.salidas as 'Total Salidas',
(sum(pur.quantity) + (war.quantity) )as 'Total Global',
(sum(pur.quantity) + (war.quantity) )- sal.salidas as Disponible 
from articles art 
    inner join warehouses_details war on war.article_id=art.id 
    inner join asd.lines linea on linea.id=art.line_id 
    inner join purchases_details pur on pur.article_id=art.id 
    inner join (SELECT sales_details.article_id,SUM(sales_details.quantity) AS salidas FROM sales_details group by sales_details.article_id) sal on sal.article_id= art.id 
where pur.purchase_id is not null and art.line_id='$categoria' 
group by art.id order by art.id ASC
```

Actualización:

De la tabla de productos necesito estos campos:

id
nombre
categoria
unidad de medida

de la tabla categoria:

id
nombre categoria

de la tabla compras_detalle

id producto
cantidad(se sumará)
id de la compra

de la tabla ventas_detalle

id producto
cantidad(se sumará)

de la tabla almacen_detalle
id producto
cantidad(se sumará)

Estoy reformulando la sentencia con left join.

Actualización 2:

En efecto con el left join me muestra los resultados tal como quiero, aún no implemento las demás tablas, pero de momento me ha arrojado todos los resultados.

aqui pongo la sentencia sql:

```
select art.id, art.name as producto, cat.name as categoria, pur.total from articles art
inner join
asd.lines cat
on
cat.id = art.line_id
left join
(select purchases_details.article_id as prod, purchases_details.purchase_id as compra,
sum(purchases_details.quantity) as total from purchases_details where purchases_details.purchase_id is not null group by purchases_details.article_id)pur
on
pur.prod=art.id 
where cat.id=5 group by art.id;
```

aqui el resultado:

[image: Resultado del left join]

Actualización 3:

Ya realicé la implementación del left join y también convertí los null a 0's eso era lo que necesitaba, gracias por la ayuda, les dejo la sentencia y la evidencia.

```
select art.id, art.name as producto,art.measure as 'U. Med', cat.name as categoria, coalesce(pur.total,0) as entradas from articles art
left join
lines cat
on
cat.id = art.line_id
left join
(select purchases_details.article_id as prod, purchases_details.purchase_id as compra,
sum(purchases_details.quantity) as total 
from purchases_details where purchases_details.purchase_id is not null group by purchases_details.article_id)pur
on
pur.prod=art.id
where cat.id=5 group by art.id;
```

El resultado:

[image: Los null convertidos a 0's]

Final:

Ya resolví toda la problemática, gracias, aqui pongo el código para quien lo ocupe, no se si este bien optimizado, pero a mi me funciona para lo que lo ocupo:

```
select art.id, 
art.name as producto,art.measure as 'U. Med', 
cat.name as categoria,
coalesce(war.inicial,0) as Inicial, 
coalesce(pur.compras,0) as Entradas, 
coalesce(sal.salidas,0) as Salidas ,
coalesce(sum(coalesce(war.inicial,0)+coalesce(pur.compras,0)),0) as 'General',
coalesce(coalesce(sum(coalesce(war.inicial,0)+coalesce(pur.compras,0)),0)-coalesce(sal.salidas,0),0) as Disponible
from articles art
left join
lines cat
on
cat.id = art.line_id
left join
(select warehouses_details.article_id as prod,
sum(warehouses_details.quantity) as inicial 
from warehouses_details group by warehouses_details.article_id)war
on
war.prod=art.id

left join
(select purchases_details.article_id as prod, purchases_details.purchase_id as compra,
sum(purchases_details.quantity) as compras 
from purchases_details where purchases_details.purchase_id is not null group by purchases_details.article_id)pur
on
pur.prod=art.id

left join 
(select sales_details.article_id as prod,
sum(sales_details.quantity) as salidas 
from sales_details group by sales_details.article_id)sal
on
sal.prod=art.id
where cat.id=5 group by art.id;
```

aquí la tabla de salida:

[image: Tabla Final]

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! probaste con un left join? sobretodo de la tabla que tiene los productos que vos buscas... por favor tambien mira [mcve]

Comment: tienes un ejemplo de tabla de salida es decir como quieres que se muestre?

Comment: cual es la tabla que tiene todos los datos que quieres ver? articles?

Comment: Hola Emmanuel, ten en cuenta los comentarios que ya te han dado, es muy importante que puedas aportar un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas para poder ayudarte adecuadamente. De todas formas te comento que el comportamiento del `inner join` es justamente lo que estás mencionando, un `inner` solo recupera las filas coincidentes de las dos tablas, tal vez lo que en realidad debieras aplicar es un `left join`.

Comment: la tabla de salida @IgmerRodriguez es esta https://ibb.co/njJ6ce, intentare con el left join.

Comment: para mi que debes seleccionar de la tabla categoria tolo lo que quiere y por cada categoria selecionar los productos:

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez estoy reformulando el join, usaré el left join, para ver como se comporta la consulta, lo haré por partes.

Comment: pon un left join en tu primer inner join